# Is Dependency Injection part of the WinUI architecture?

Tags: dependency-injection, winui

Dependency Injection has been baked into the .NET 6 Web application architecture. I know I can add bits and pieces of DI from Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection package to build a WinUI application, but I'm wondering if something more integrated to the new architecture is available.

Comment: WinUI3 is a set of native-written component. Its usage is not limited to .NET. When you use WinUI3 you "just" use a *projection* of it (using C#/WinRT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is Dependency Injection part of the WinUI architecture?

No. WinUI is not an "architecture". It's a native (and in version 3 completely decoupled) UI platform component for Windows.

Having that said, you can of course implement dependency injection in your WinUI apps but there is no equivlent of the `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` package included in the Windows App SDK.